# Циклы и функции

Tags: jquery, html5

Не могу понять почему не работает!Функия должна добавлять блоки div пока количество фраз не будет равно 5!

```js
var Number = 5 ;
var div = $('.test>div').length;
console.log(div);
function Add(){
  while(Number == div){div++;$('.test').append('<div></div>')}
}
Add();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Вы хоть напишите чего вы ожидаете от кода

Comment: `while(Number > div)`

Comment: Не работает так, пример приведите!

Comment: Я не рекомендую использовать имена базовых объектов в качестве переменных. К таким относится, в частности, `Number`. Это чревато долгой отладкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var MAX_DIV_COUNT = 5;
var divCount = $('.test>div').length;
console.log(divCount);
function Add() {
  while(divCount < MAX_DIV_COUNT) {
    divCount++;
    $('.test').append(
      '<div style="border:1px solid black;background-color:red;height:10px;"></div>');
  }
}
Add();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div style="border:1px solid black;background-color:red;height:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: может `const MAX_DIV_COUNT = 5;`